# Flutter show toast above keyboard on IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, toast

I'm using fluttertoast 7.0.4 package to show toasts in my App but on IOS that toast isn't showed when the key board is opened "it actually appears behind the keyboard" this is my code

```
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: message,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.strongOrange,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
);
```

is there any way to change the z-index and making it bigger than keyboard's z-index in flutter

Answer (score 8):

You cannot show Fluttertoast above the keyboard in ios.

There are two options:

1.Change the gravity of toast to center

```
   Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: message,
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0
      );
```

2. Hide keyboard when showing toast at the bottom.

   ```
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
   ```

Comment: Not the best option, but a nice trick. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

Other option would be to display the Toast just after the keyboard.

The important thing is to use

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom
```

when displaying the Fluttertoast using the option "Toast with BuildContext (All Platforms)" (more info in https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast)
This will get you the size of the keyboard, with that then you can manually put an offset and won't be occluded by the keyboard.

A pseudo code would be:

```
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

FToast()
  ..init(context)
  ..showToast(
    child: <YOUR WIDGET>,
    positionedToastBuilder: (context, child) {
      return Positioned(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        top: 16.0,
        left: 16.0,
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
```